# Copying files from another directory with shellscript

Tags: linux, shell

I have a question, I have a script that takes a file and copy it to several computers. but my question is the file is in /opt/scripts but the files to copy are in /opt/file/copy. how can I do without moving the file from its directories.

````
#Here I put a list or array of my server endings
IPS=('15' )

#Name of the file to copy t
FILE="$1"
DIRECTORY1=/opt/bots

# if number of parameters less than or equal to 0
if [ $# -le 0 ]; then
    echo "The tar name must be entered."
    exit 1
fi

# I loop through the array or list with a for
for i in ${IPS[@]}
    do
        xxxxxxxx

done```
````

Comment: If to _do without moving the file from its directories_ is your only problem, just present your solution with moving, and surely we can modify it to work without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy files from serverA (in /sourcedirectory) to serverB (in /targetdirectory), you can use `scp`, assuming `ssh` is setup.

On serverA, do:

```
cd /sourcedirectory
scp file useronserverB@serverB:/targetdirectory/
```

Then the file on serverA did not move, and it is copied into the /targetdirectory on serverB.